# Vue multiselect with axios call to database, laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, multi-select

For some reason, I can't quite figure out how to get an 'autocomplete' style multiselect with Vue working properly.

I properly set the route that is being called in my axios block, and the controller is set to use the query as a way to hit the database with a LIKE clause, but something is going wrong somewhere and my multiselect is not being filled with results from database that would make it searchable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Route:

```
Route::get('search', 'Controller@searchTags')
    ->name('search');
```

Controller:

```
public function searchTags(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->get('query')) {
        $query = $request->get('query');
        $data = TAGS::where('TAG_DATA', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

        $output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:block; position:relative">';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output .= '<li><a href="#">' . $row->tag_data . '</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
<div id="tagContent">
    <multiselect v-model="value" open-direction="bottom" :options="options" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :taggable="true" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Add Tag(s)" label="name" track-by="name">
        <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"><span class="multiselect__single" v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} options selected</span></template>
    </multiselect>
</div>

new Vue({
        components: {
            Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
        },
        data () {
            return {
                value: [],
                options: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            read(){
                window.axios.get('campaigns/search').then(({ data }) =>{
                    console.log(data)
                });
            },
            addTag (newTag) {
              const tag = {
                name: newTag,
                code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
              }
              this.options.push(tag)
              this.value.push(tag)
            }
        }
    }).$mount('#tagContent');
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're asking vue to do anything with the data returned from the axios request. I also suspect you'll have an easier time if you just return data from your route and then let the vue handle markup creation.

Comment: How do you mean, as far as your 2nd comment?

Comment: @ebbishop what should I do exactly for the data returned? I guess that's where I'm mostly stuck right now. There are too many elements to load on page load so I really wanted to try the axios call for autocomplete

Comment: It needs to be sent to the vue multiselect component as options, so that the component can render the data. It looks like you're intending the vue data property `options` to populate the multiselect - when you have data returned from your route, you could do something like `this.options = data`. What's unclear to me is why you're using the controller to process the data into markup and what you expect to happen with that markup.

Comment: True, the controller has some leftover formatting that I kept for testing, but I see what you mean. I could remove the formatting and just return the results as a json object I guess

Comment: @ebbishop I'm still a bit lost as to where to point the options to the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things missing from your example, I believe.

1. You need to trigger the `read` function when the search input changes - use the `@search-change` event for that
2. You need to make use of the results of your axios request by sending them to `this.options`, so that the `multiselect` component can make use of them.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/21Lujocy/), I've mocked the data request using a timeout, but you should get the idea. You can also make use of the `loading` property to let your users know something is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: ok I think I see now, thanks! So my axios call would actually be where your timeout function is and I could just set this.options = data there

Comment: ```axios.get('campaigns/search')
                         .then(response => this.options = response.data)
                         .catch(error => {});``` something like this?

Comment: @TomN. Yep! Give that a shot.

Comment: I actually changed it do this so that it sends the 'query' i need in the controller:
```axios.get('campaigns/search',{params: {query: this.val}})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        self.options = response.data;
                });```
But still no results. However, I see the response in my console with the json of all my data